# Why does my 3D model disappear after applying remesh modifier?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I want to apply the Remesh modifier to a 3D model but when doing so, the model disappears.

I have very limited experience using Blender and have been unable to find anyone describing a similar problem (except for 2D text).

A blender file which reproduces the problem: http://www.filedropper.com/remeshtest

Comment: Have you tried unchecking "Remove disconnected faces" ? By default the remesh modifier only keeps one island

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: You need to up the "Octree Depth" higher than 10 or 11 but you will end up with way more geometry than what you have now

Comment: @Gorgious You are right. Increasing Octree Depth fixes it. As you note, the number of mesh vertices is increased substantially which unfortunately defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments: the model disappears because the default "Octree Depth" is too small in this particular instance. Increasing the Octree Depth sufficiently solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remesh modifier needs mesh with volume to work properly .
Flat meshes gives blank output as it cant compute the volume and mesh with holes produce a result with the holes filled.

also try instantMesh app [github link](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes)
might give usable results

If you want to remesh flat/surface/text objects then use solidify before remesh then delete the extra thickness after applying the modifiers

Comment: This is not the issue in this instance since the mesh is not flat